# socket.io implementing a simple chat

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I tried to ask this on the socket.io google group but no one could (or didn't wanted to) help me.

I have this piece of code on the server side:

```
var chat = io
  .of('/chat')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('message', {
        that: 'only'
      , '/chat': 'will get'
    });
  });

chat.on("message", function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

While on the client side I have this code:

```
  var chat = io.connect('http://localhost/chat');

  chat.on('message', function (data) {
    chat.emit('hi!');
  });

  chat.emit("message", {"this": "is a message"});
```

On the console I can see that the first message from the server is sent but it seems like the client, once connected and received the message, doesn't emit the `'hi!'` message. Moreover I want the client to emit also another message, namely the last line I pasted. Also this message is not received by the server (which in theory should log it).

I'm surely doing something wrong, can anyone point out where exactly this is happening?
What I want to achieve in the end is just setting up a simple chat-like system, but I want this stuff (the channels) working before actually writing the chat itself. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why that it doesn't the "hi" is not sent is because the first argument in `.emit` is the event name, in which in here, it is "hi". Technically if you do the following on the server side, I think you should get an undefined data(since you didn't put anything as the second argument which is the object to be sent):

```
.on('hi',function(data){
  console.log(data) // should log "undefined"
});
```

You can also use `.send` which is like the web-sockets semantics, and sends to the the `message` event. If you change the `.emit` to `.send` in the client side, it should work.

In summary:

```
.emit('eventName', 'data') // sends to the eventName name
.send('data') // sends to message event
```

Working client side code:

```
  var chat = io.connect('http://localhost/chat');

  chat.on('message', function (data) {
    chat.send('hi!');
  });

  chat.emit("message", {"this": "is a message"});
```

Answer (score 1):

I dumbed it down a little bit, but:

Server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

var chat = io
  .of('/chat')
  .on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.send('welcome to the interwebs');
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
```

Client:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://10.120.28.201:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var chat = io.connect('http://10.120.28.201:8080/chat');

  chat.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("connected");
    chat.send('hi!');
    chat.on('message', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```